# htaccess RewriteRules Strange behavior

Tags: .htaccess

Soo i have this htaccess file in my subfolder for a project:

```
RewriteEngine On

# HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}  !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R]

RewriteRule ^homepage$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^news$ news.php [L]
RewriteRule ^store$ store.php [L]
RewriteRule ^staff$ teams.php?t=1 [L]
```

In this file "homepage" works, "news" works and "staff" too but "store" not
I had a similar problem last week but i abandoned it becouse i tried everything:
`RewriteRule ^/?news/(.*)$ news.php?art=$1 [L]`
Here i want a rewrite rule /news/foobar to /news.php?art=foobar
I know i maybe not understand htaccess fully but if some work why others not?
It can be usefull information i use **LiteSpeed Webserver**

Comment: What error do you get when you go to  `/store` ?

Comment: @AmitVerma 404 not found but the file is there

Comment: Try and disable `MultiViews`, that is often the culprit in cases where you have such partial overlaps between the “fake” path, and actual file names.

Comment: @CBroe Sadly no change i dont really know whats happening here...

Comment: Does the `store.php` file exist in your `/subfolder`? Try adding a base to your htaccess `RewriteBase /subfolder/`  or try changing the destination file path from `store.php` to `/subfolder/store.php`  in your rule

Comment: https://url.example/hdhprojects/versus/store soo this is my link that is not working and i tried Rewritebase too the root has a htaccess too, but i tried to remove it too nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Soo this is just an answer who has this same problem when you use cyberpanel/openlitespeed you need to restart lsws everytime when you modify your .htaccess only then it will work.
If you use OLS Enterprise you dont need to do this...